# Calendars for non-working days for business purposes

Tags: java, calendar, billing, business-rules

I am interested in creating a business calendar with the Bank Holidays per country.
I was wondering e.g. I know that some holidays are "fixed" for all years to come for instance easter variant holidays.
But are in general bank holidays "fixed"?
I mean

1. if I define bank holidays for this year would it need to change it in a
   couple of years?
2. Is there a standard approach for this kind of thing? Is there a
   reference implementation I could see?

Comment: 1: Yes. 2: In my experience this is entirely dependent on the business.